# Assign values in JSON array to variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a query that upon being JSON encoded, and `print_r()` looks like this:

```
Array
(    
    [response] => Array
        (
            [numFound] => 2392
            [start] => 0
            [maxScore] => 1
            [docs] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [stats] => Array
        (
            [stats_fields] => Array
                (
                    [q_one] => Array
                        (
                            [min] => 0.0059
                            [max] => 6.0095
                            [count] => 2392
                            [missing] => 0
                            [sum] => 53.9131
                            [sumOfSquares] => 48.16448107
                            [mean] => 0.022538921404682
                            [stddev] => 0.14012800795752
                            [facets] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [q_two] => Array
                        (
                            [min] => 0
                            [max] => 0.0075
                            [count] => 2392
                            [missing] => 0
                            [sum] => 17.67
                            [sumOfSquares] => 0.132525
                            [mean] => 0.0073871237458194
                            [stddev] => 0.00091333432809989
                            [facets] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                    [q_three] => Array
                        (
                            [min] => 0
                            [max] => 0.065
                            [count] => 2392
                            [missing] => 0
                            [sum] => 153.14
                            [sumOfSquares] => 9.9541
                            [mean] => 0.064021739130435
                            [stddev] => 0.0079155641768643
                            [facets] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Within `stats >> stats_fields` I want to write a `foreach` loop that captures the names of each header:  `q_one`, `q_two`, and `q_three`, but I'm not sure how to do that.

I can capture the elements inside each of these 3 'headers', because their names are static, (e.g. - each one has a `min` and a `max` element)

```
foreach ($json['stats']['stats_fields'] as $j) {
  echo $j['min']
}
```

but I'm not sure how to get the header names...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get them in an array with `array_keys()`:

```
$headers = array_keys($json['stats']['stats_fields']);
```

Or get them in the loop if you need it there using `$key => $value` syntax:

```
foreach ($json['stats']['stats_fields'] as $key => $j) {
  echo $key;
  echo $j['min'];
}
```